# How to remove rows in Excel where inclusions are not met?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, say I have two columns:

```
ID, Code
1 A
1 B
1 G
2 A
2 F
3 A
3 B
3 C
3 F
4 B
```

I want to delete any rows for which the ID number is not associated with both A and B somewhere.

So for example all the rows with ID=1 are OK to keep because it is associated with code A and code B.

All rows with ID=2 are to be deleted because it has A, but no B.

All rows with ID=3 are OK because it has both A and B.

All rows with ID=4 are to be deleted because it only has B, no A.

The real file has many rows so I can't do this by hand. Is there a quicker way? I tried using Vlookups somehow but I can't find a way to easily tell which ones to delete.

Comment: You can write a macro or simply do it manually by using tools like filter. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried filter but there wasn't a way to do what I needed, and I don't know how to write a macro that will do this

Comment: `I tried filter but there wasn't a way to do what I needed` -- Really? It might be cumbersome to filter ... but this CAN BE done via filter.

Comment: (1) Is the data sorted by ID? (2) Is the data also sorted by Col B (A, B, C...)

Comment: I wound up figuring out the macro but I will verify my results with the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"A")+COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"B")
```

Delete all the results that returns 0 or 1 (and keep all the results that give 2).

Answer (score 1):

using 2 temporary helper columns in C & D

1st column `= A2 & B2`, copied down
2nd column `=IF( OR( ISERROR(Vlookup(A2 & "A",C:C,1,FALSE)),ISERROR(Vlookup(A2 & "A",C:C,1,FALSE))),"DeleteMe","SaveMe")`

Follow Instructions in column D

Delete Columns C & D

Don't forget to try this on a backup first, so you can enure it works to your satisfaction